# "AT-SPI D-Bus Bus" program starts on debian 9 xfce start up

Tags: debian, xfce, autostart

I was curious to learn about AT-SPI D-Bus Bus.

From [this](https://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/manage-the-startup-applications/) website I found the definition of AT-SPI D-Bus Bus:

> AT SPI stands for Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface, a
> framework to integrate accessibility functions in applications. This
> command will create a new DBus for AT SPI specific functions.

I also found a weird definition in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_Technology_Service_Provider_Interface):

> Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface (AT-SPI) is a
> platform-neutral framework for providing bi-directional communication
> between assistive technologies (AT) and applications.[3] It is the de
> facto standard for providing accessibility to free and open desktops,
> like GNU/Linux or OpenBSD, led by the GNOME Project.

Between Assistive technologies and applications?

Assistive technology are targeted for users with disabilities. Is this program only meant to use by Linux accessibility applications like Orca?

All the references of this program are for GNOME and I use xfce. Is this also needed for xfce? Did anyone try to stop the auto-start of this program?

Comment: The Wikipedia page you cited pretty much answers your questions.